# Скрипт, удаляющий содержимое определенной директории

Tags: php

Ребята, нужен скрипт (или намекните хотя бы), который смог бы очищать папку с файлами, при этом не удаляя ее саму.

Answer (score 3):

Первая ссылка в поисковике выдала этот результат:

```
  function removeDirectory($dir) {
    if ($objs = glob($dir."/*")) {
       foreach($objs as $obj) {
         is_dir($obj) ? removeDirectory($obj) : unlink($obj);
       }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
  }
```

Нам остается только "правильно" убрать `rmdir($dir);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = ...

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
        $dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
    ),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    if ($item->isDir()) {
        rmdir($item->getPathname());
    } else {
        unlink($item->getPathname());
    }
}
```